# How to open web browser in a loop and enter data and wait until it fully loads

Tags: c#, webbrowser-control

I have a C# form with a web browser control on it. I want to open a url eg:(www. google.com)in a loop and for each time the loop runs I want to first navigate to the url fill a search string and click the search button and wait until the search results load fully.

How can I do this?

I wrote this code to save the url that we get after search result loads but only the search result for the last string seems to load and gets saved in my list.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var task = DoNavigationAsync();
    task.ContinueWith((t) =>
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Done!");
    }, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
}

private void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    HtmlElement url = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("sb_form_q");

    if (url != null)
    {
        url.SetAttribute("value", search[searchindx-1]);
        webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("sb_form_go").InvokeMember("click");
    }

    if (webBrowser1.Url.ToString() != "http://www.bing.com/")
    {
        SavedUrl.Add(webBrowser1.Url.ToString());
    }
}

async Task DoNavigationAsync()
{
    TaskCompletionSource<bool> tcsNavigation = null;
    TaskCompletionSource<bool> tcsDocument = null;

    this.webBrowser1.Navigated += (s, e) =>
    {
        if (tcsNavigation.Task.IsCompleted)
            return;
        tcsNavigation.SetResult(true);
    };

    this.webBrowser1.DocumentCompleted += (s, e) =>
    {
        if (this.webBrowser1.ReadyState != WebBrowserReadyState.Complete)
            return;
        if (tcsDocument.Task.IsCompleted)
            return;
        tcsDocument.SetResult(true);
    };
    search = new string[3];
    search[0] = "C";
    search[1] = "C++";
    search[2] = "C#";

    searchindx = 0;

    foreach (string sval in search)
    {
        searchindx++;
        tcsNavigation = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();
        tcsDocument = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();

        webBrowser1.Navigate("www.bing.com");

        await tcsNavigation.Task;

        await tcsDocument.Task;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it necessary for you to display this in your GUI or could you as well do this in background?

Comment: Selenium would work well for this.

Comment: @Franz: It is not necessary to show it in the GUI. It's okay to do it in the background.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the async `HttpClient` from .NET Framework 4.5, you can load a web page without using a gui element such as `WebBrowser`.

A download would look like this:

```
using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient()) {
    await client.GetStringAsync("https://google.com");
}
```

This would get you the HTML content of the google search site.

But if you just want to have the resulting URL, you won't even need to perform a download because google (and most other search engines) provides an API for that. Note the following google URL: `https://www.google.com/search?q=google`. You can see that the search string "google" appears as parameter named "q". So if you build your code like this...

```
string[] search = new string[] { "C", "C++", "C#" };

foreach (string sval in search)
{
    // C# <= 5
    SavedUrl.Add(string.Format("https://google.com/search?q={0}", sval));
    // C# 6
    SavedUrl.Add($"https://google.com/search?q={sval}");
}
```

... you won't need any web access.